# how can I capture the value from the scenario which loaded from scenario library

Tags: fitnesse, scenarios

Here is the case: I create scenario library, the test page include the scenario library, I want to use var1 in scenarioA as scenarioB's para. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean scenarioA assigns a value to var1 (has a line with the first cell `$var1=`) and in your test page's script you first call scenarioA and after that you want to call scenarioB from your script and pass it the value of `$var1` as one of its arguments? (It is easier to give answers if you include example tables for both scenarioA and scenarioB and the test script using them.)

Comment: Hi Fried, it works when i call scenarioA and B from one script table, thanks a lot!